# How to save a file created on python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, nan, file-handling

I have created the following code which reads and then cleans the data in the file by removing all the rows with NaN values and gives a count of how many such rows exist. The count part runs just fine but I am not able to save the new file that I have created that has no rows with Null values. How do I save this ***new_data*** file?

```
data = parse('PAAD.gct')

new_data = data.data_df.dropna(axis = 0, how ='any') 

print("Old data frame length:", len(data.data_df), "\nNew data frame length:",  
       len(new_data), "\nNumber of rows with at least 1 NA value: ", 
       (len(data.data_df)-len(new_data))) 
write(new_data , 'new_file.gct')
```

I am getting the following error on running this code

```
AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'data_df'
```

Comment: What is `data_df`? If it's a `pandas.DataFrame` object, dont put `data.` before it. You can save a df with [`pandas.DataFrame.to_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.2/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html).

Comment: If i do so then i get an error `data_df ` is not defined

Comment: Please share the entire error message, and a [mcve].

Comment: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Answer (score 0):

you need to open the file and write to is as follow

```
 f = open('new_file.gct', 'w')
    f.write(str(new_data))
```

Comment: ----> 9 f = open('new_file.gct',new_data)
     10 f.write(new_data)
     11 

TypeError: open() argument 2 must be str, not DataFrame

Comment: f.write(str(new_data))